# Animal thisIsACat = new Cat(); - Is this an implicit conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

Given this example:

`Animal thisIsACat = new Cat();`

Is there an implicit conversion from `Cat` to `Animal`?

**For clarification:**

Assume:

```
class Animal
{

}

class Cat: Animal
{

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

Note that this IS an implicit conversion (it is defined in §6.1.6 by the specification) but it does NOT change the referential identity of the object being converted.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks. After I posted the question I remembered something similar I had seen before. The CLR is just pretending it's an animal, but there is no conversion. An object can ever only be of one type, and polymorphic behavior doesn't change it's type, the CLR just acts like it is of a type. A conversion means you actually create a new object of a specific type with whatever conversion algorithm is specified.  :-)

Comment: I agree this is an example of polymorphism, but I did find this note on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: There is an implicit reference conversion from a derived class to a base class defined by the specification (§6.1.6) but note that they DO NOT change the referential identity of the object being converted.

Comment: I like the term 'subtype polymorphism', but it is still an implicit conversion from a supertype to a subtype.  ;)

Comment: @Jason: Awesome, thanks for "implicit _reference conversion_"! It's the reference that is "converted", right?

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: It changes the type of the reference, but NOT the type of the object being referred to.

Answer (score 3):

There's no conversion there - your object is a `Cat` and will always be a `Cat` - only the variable is listed as an `Animal`, not the object itself.

A conversion would be where you take a `Cat` object, do something to it, and suddenly you now have a different object of type `Animal`. Doesn't really make sense in this situation.

When dealing with structs, conversions make more sense. The `Integer` 5 can be converted into the `Decimal` 5m, and they are two totally different objects.

The code:

```
int i = 5;
decimal d = i;
```

would be an implicit conversion, because 5 is a `System.Int32`, but it is converted into 5m, which is a `System.Decimal`, and a completely different object than the original.

Comment: Of course it is a conversion. **A conversion need not be representation-changing.** Representation-preserving conversions are still conversions.

Comment: I didn't realize that a reference conversion would be considered a conversion. The practical use of the word Convert, at least to me, is taking one object and changing (a.k.a. converting) it, not just changing the reference. But I guess it all depends on your point of view - in my point of view, that specific Cat object is not changing or converting in any way, only the reference to it, and the object is the important thing to me, not the reference. But that's just me...

Comment: OK, suppose you take an int containing the number 123, and you convert it to a uint. Is that a conversion or not?  The bits are exactly the same. But the *operations* you can perform on those bits are *different*. That's what makes a conversion a conversion; it's not that the bits are different, it's that the bits behave differently.

Comment: In that scenario, from a practical point of view, the `int` 123 and the `uint` 123 are different objects - you can verify this by calling GetType() on them: `((uint)123).GetType().Name` will give you UInt32, while `123.GetType().Name` will give you Int32. Those are clearly two different objects. Maybe not technically once you start talking about the actual bits sitting on the physical memory locations - in the end, everything's just a series of bits - but day to day, they are different objects. Again, just a point of view that makes sense to me as a .NET developer.

Comment: Joe: but a value type does not contain any information inside it that describes its type!  That's part of what makes a value type a value type: it contains only the bits of its value, and not the bits of its metadata. **When you call "GetType" on those bits, it is *the compiler* that generates code which tells the CLR "hey, this thing has been cast to UINT, so you need to treat this thing as a boxed UINT"**  The runtime engine neither knows nor cares what type those bits have except when the compiler tells it to.

Comment: My point is that they are in no way "two different objects" from the runtime's point of view. The only difference between ((int)123).GetType() and ((uint)123).GetType() is whether the compiler emits instructions that say "box these 32 bits as an int before you call GetType" or "box these 32 bits as a uint before you call GetType". The value -- the 32 bits in some register -- is the same. The boxed values are of course different, but those boxed values are *only generated when GetType is called*.

Comment: The same is true of "values" which are references to reference types. Sure, each instance of the reference type describes itself. But, so what?  What is relevant to the type system is *what the compiler says about how the reference is to be treated*, not *what the reference refers to.*

Comment: All that said, it is quite confusing I agree that we use "conversion" to mean both representation-changing and representation-preserving conversions. They are fundamentally different.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that `Animal` is an interface (or abstract class). The data type Cat must implement the Animal interface ... so yes, you have an implicit conversion from `new Cat()` to Animal. The conversion from Animal to Cat must be explicit: e.g.  `(Cat)thisIsACat`

Read on into the resource on subtype polymorphism and you will see: [OriginsThe notion of subtyping in programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism) dates back to the 1960s; it was introduced in Simula derivatives. The first formal treatments of subtyping were given by John C. Reynolds in 1980 who used category theory to formalize [implicit conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_conversion), and Luca Cardelli (1985).

Specifically, in this case, we have 2 types: Animal and Cat. Cat is a subtype of Animal: type conversion, typecasting, and coercion refers to different ways of, implicitly or explicitly, changing an entity of one data type into another